# how can i get on click to check what check box is checked and if button is pressed

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get my on click method to listen for submit button and check what check box is checked to load a certain activity based on that check box here is what code i have for this function but it keeps crashing my android app. Can somebody please indicate what i may be doing wrong . please ignore any spelling or grammer mistakes as i have dilexsia.

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.submit) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ModeSelect.this, OnePSetup.class);         
    if (checkBox.isChecked()){
        startActivity(intent);
        System.out.println("checked");
    }
}
```

This is the outpu error

```
    11-14 15:36:09.820  12457-12478/allanwalls1304988.straight4 E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4057be0
```

11-14 15:36:11.952  12457-12457/allanwalls1304988.straight4 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: allanwalls1304988.straight4, PID: 12457
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference
            at allanwalls1304988.straight4.ModeSelect.onClick(ModeSelect.java:58)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: There is not enough code here to understand what can go wrong. basically the checkbox might be null or the activity is not declared on the manifest.

Comment: But i am listening correctly ?

Comment: I don't see that you're listening at all.  You are checking a condition but that's not the same as listening. You'd add something like a ClickListener to the Checkbox to trigger when the box is (un)checked.

Comment: This is my listening method here

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mode_select);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

Answer (score 1):

From stack trace you posted, the error is at ModeSelect.java line number 58 and the error is on the execution of this line `checkBox.isChecked()`. It seems that you haven't initilized `checkBox` which causes it to throw NullPointerException. You can initilized it like this:

`CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.myCheckBox);`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your checkbox is referenced with a local variable inside onCreate() method make it field reference. It shouldn't give null pointer then.
 Declare it as a field

```
private CheckBox checkBox;
```

inside `onCreate()` method

```
checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
```